# Can I use the same cursor while looping through it?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, database-cursor

I am iterating through a `SELECT` result, like this:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = 127.0.0.1, user = ...) # and so on
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")

for row in cur:
    # some stuff I'm doing
    # sometimes I need to perform another SELECT here
```

The question is, can I use `cur` again inside the `for` loop, or do I have to create another cursor (or even more - another connection)?

I guess I am missing some basic knowledge about databases or Python here... I am actually quite new with both. Also, my attempts to google the answer have failed.

I would even guess myself that *I have to create another cursor*, but I think I have actually used it for some time like this before I realized that it might be wrong and it seemed to work. But I am a bit confused now and can't guarantee it. So I just want to make sure.

Comment: You could do something like `results = cur.execute(blah)` and then iterate over `results` instead and then reuse the cursor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a new cursor. Otherwise, `cur` is now holding the results of your new "inner" select instead of your "outer" one.

This *may* work anyway, depending on your database library and your luck, but you shouldn't count on it. I'll try to explain below.

You don't need a new connection, however.

So:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")

for row in cur:
    # some stuff I'm doing
    inner_cur = conn.cursor()
    inner_cur.execute("SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE column = row[1]")
    for inner_row in inner_cur:
        # stuff
```

---

So, why does it sometimes work?

Well, let's look at what a `for row in cur:` loop really does under the covers:

```
temp_iter = iter(cur)
while True:
    try:
        row = next(temp_iter)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # your code runs here
```

Now, that `iter(cur)` calls the `__iter__` method on the cursor object. What does that do? That's up to `cur`, an object of the cursor type provided by your database library.

The obvious implementation is to return some kind of iterator that has a reference to either the cursor object, or to the same row collection that the cursor object is using under the covers. This is what happens when you call `iter` on a list, for example.

But there's nothing *requiring* the database library to implement its `__iter__` that way. It could create a copy of the row set for the iterator to use. Or, more plausibly, it could make the iterator refer to the current row set… but then change the cursor itself to refer to a *different* one when you next call `execute`. If it does *that*, then the old iterator keeps reading the old row set, and you can get a new iterator that iterates the new row set.

You shouldn't rely on that happening just because a database library is *allowed* to do that. But you also shouldn't rely on it *not* happening, of course.

In more concrete terms, imagine this type:

```
class Cursor(object):
    # other stuff
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.rowset)
    def execute(self, sql, *args):
        self.rowset = self.db.do_the_real_work(sql, *args)
```